# How to install a pfx certificate to Azure so Worker Role can access a third-party Web Service?

Tags: azure, ssl, x509certificate, azure-worker-roles, pfx

My Worker Role whose job it is to download data from a third party web service, requires accessing the service provider with a certificate. Having installed the pfx certificate to Personal Store on my development machine, I can easily HttpClient my way to utilising the service.

So what is the equivalent of installing the pfx certificate in Azure for the published Worker Role?

Please note that during testing, the certificate is self signed with no root CA so importing from disk via new X509Certificate instance will not work.

Thanks

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response =  client.GetAsync(new Uri("foo")).Result;
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think installing a PFX certificate in a worker role is similar to installing a SSL certificate in a web role.

Step 1: Upload the PFX file in Cloud Services Certificates in Azure Portal.

Step 2: Specify the certificate details in the Cloud Services configuration section. If you're using Visual Studio, then double click on the Role --> Certificates tab --> Add Certificate and specifying the name, certificate store location and the thumbprint.

Then when the role gets deployed, this certificate will automatically gets installed in the VM running your role.